# PySide2 QTextEdit setup markdown css in maya

Tags: maya, pyside2

I want to see a view in the form of markdown in Maya. The next code is to try it.

````
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets

message = """
```python
import pymel.core as pm

print("Hello World")
```
  
# Test Message
## Test Message
"""

dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(dialog)
web_engine = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
p_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ok")

layout.addWidget(web_engine)
layout.addWidget(p_btn)

doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
doc.setMarkdown(message)

web_engine.setHtml(doc.toHtml())

p_btn.clicked.connect(dialog.accept)

dialog.setWindowTitle("Notes")
dialog.exec_()
````

[image]

However, as a result, the code block does not display properly. I'm trying to add markdown CSS to HTML, but no progress has been made. I need your help.

Comment: you are not using the correct code fences.  You are using single quote `'` when you should be using backtick `\``

Comment: oh. There was a mistake in posting. The result of `\`` is the picture below.